# is it legal to cut of factory stab in plugs and replace with wire nuts

Tags: electrical

Electric code on wiring lights with factory stab in plugs can stab in plugs be removed and replaced with wire nuts

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the connectors?

Answer (score 4):

Yes... Maybe... Technically, probably not.

But let's talk first about *why* you want to cut off the quick connect fitting.  If you want to remove the factory installed connector, because you've read all over the internet about how bad "backstab" terminals are. I understand your concern, but you're probably overreacting.  The "backstab" terminals the internet rants about, were poorly designed terminals that were built into devices (receptacles, switches, etc.). Modern "*push-fit*" connectors are a bit different, and are designed with past failures in mind.

It's very common for newer light fixtures; especially recessed fixtures, to include "*push-fit*" connectors. These connectors make wiring the fixture easier, and are used by most installers. These new connectors seem to be reliable, and don't appear to suffer the same failures as the old "*backstab*" terminals. However, loads of folks still have a bias against these connectors, because of the poorly designed "*backstabs*" that proceeded them.

`</rant>`

---

As for removing the factory installed connectors. Technically, removing them is modifying a factory assembly. Which *technically* probably voids the UL listing. And is *technically* against National Electrical Code, since you're not installing the fixture according to the manufacturer's installation instructions.

However, I'm sure loads of people do it, and it's doubtful that an inspector would ever fail an inspection because of it. As long as you use the proper sized twist-on wire connector, and make a solid connection. There should be no problem removing the connector, and using twist-on wire connectors instead.

---

***NOTES:***

- *I don't have any statistical data on push-fit connector failures, so have no way to prove if they're better or worse than backstab terminals. At the end of the day, it's about your peace of mind. If you're not comfortable with push-fit connectors, then don't use them.*

Comment: Wow guess I was on my outlet back stab rant will delete thanks Tester. +

Comment: Even when a problem is resolved, people are skittish for decades after.  And with some validity: sometimes the "new improved" turns out later to be as half-baked as the original.  You never know and it ends up being subjective.  I'm a big fan of aluminum wire, but not stabs.  Why one and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do maintenance work and get good outlets. I would look to see if you can release the wire so you don't need to cut it off. Code requires wire length 6" from the back of the box Or Minimum 3" clear of the box so there is enough wire to safely wire the devices. Most stabs next to the hole there is a slot that a piece of wire can be pressed into to release the stab so it doesn't need to be cut. Some times you need to push in on the wire in the stab to get it to release. So I would not cut them unless I had to. I have come across 1 job that did not have the release these I cut and pig tailed together with a short wire going to the outlet the inspector was fine with this. Code Ref 2014 NEC 300.14

Comment: You know you can edit your posts, right?  You don't have to delete them and start over.

Comment: Your answer was good mine went the wrong way.

Comment: On an outlet, I don't cut them off.  I just wrestle them out.  They are solid copper (by definition) so they can take it.  Also if you cut them off, scrap the outlet as it now has little hot bits sticking out the back.

Answer (score 0):

Lights, you say?   Ok the key rule is:

Don't reuse stabs.

Either pull the wire out of the stab (but don't damage the wire) or cut the wire off.

Yes, it's fine to use wire nuts in the US.

On some fixtures (i.e. Fluorescent) you are stuck with stabs going into fixture parts like sockets. Remember, don't reuse stabs, so don't pull the wire out of it.  Spare as much wire as you can and use wire nuts. (don't trim the wire back to match the ballast leads; the *next* ballast may have shorter leads.). On a fluorescent fuxture you'll use a lot of blue wire nuts.